# Italicize text within \cvlistitem using moderncv

Tags: moderncv, italic

Using `moderncv`, I want to italicize some text within a list generated by `\cvlistitem`, but I'm having a hard time fighting the default formatting. I don't want to change the formatting for the entire field, and `\emph{}` and `\textit{}` aren't working.

I'd like something like:

```
\section{Professional Service}
\cvlistitem{Member of \emph{Conferency Conference} steering committee}
\cvlistitem{Current reviewer for academic journals: \emph{Prestigious Journal of Science}, \emph{Prestigious Journal of Mathematics}}
```

I'm sure there's a simple answer, but I'm new to TeX and would appreciate some help.

Edit: Italics show up when using style `casual`, `classic`, and `fancy`, but not when using `banking` or `oldstyle`. I'd like to use `banking`.

Comment: In the code above, you don't close out (`}`) the `\cvlistitem` commands properly. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Oh, no. That was just me being incautious when typing out some examples here. Brackets added (and included, of course, in the real document).

Comment: @newgam: I can't seem to replicate the problem. Using your code, [I can see italicized text](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFEi1.png).

Comment: @Werner: I noticed that you used the default "casual" style, so I tried that along with all of the other style options included in moderncv. Italics show up when using "casual", "classic", and "fancy," but not when using "banking" or "oldstyle". I'd like to use "banking."

Answer (score 3):

Well, adding your shown code into the file `example.tex` of current class `moderncv` (version 2.0.0) I have no problem seeing the italic words with your mentioned style `banking` (in an comment) ...

Because you gave us no other informations I can only guess you are using an older version of class `moderncv` or an outdated TeX distribution with an included outdated `moderncv`.

Please copy the following MWE to your computer and compile it three times.  Then check your log file, at the end you should find an list of used class, packages and version numbers! This list is the result of the command `\listfiles` I added into the MWE.

Please add this list to your question, if it differs to mine list later ...

MWE:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

%\nopagenumbers{} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Professional Service}
\cvlistitem{Member of \emph{Conferency Conference} steering committee}
\cvlistitem{Current reviewer for academic journals: 
  \emph{Prestigious Journal of Science}, 
  \emph{Prestigious Journal of Mathematics}%
}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}

\end{document}
```

giving the result:

[image]

with the following list of used packages and version numbers:

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2016/07/01 v0.06i Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/06/02 v1.0s Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
fancyhdr.sty    
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2016/05/14 v2.6a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2016/05/14 v2.6a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2016/05/14 v2.6a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter compatibility patches
moderncvstylebanking.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: banking
tgpagella.sty    2009/09/27 v1.2 TeX Gyre Pagella as default roman family
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
moderncviconsawesome.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter icons: awesome
fontawesome.sty    2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons
fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
moderncvheadiii.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 3
moderncvbodyiii.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body variant: 3
   t1qpl.fd    2009/09/25 v1.2 font definition file for T1/qpl
ufontawesometwo.fd    2016/05/22 Font definitions for U/fontawesometwo.
moderncvcolorblue.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: blue
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
geometry.cfg
hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
  mt-ppl.cfg    2005/11/16 v1.6 microtype config. file: Palatino (RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

BTW: I'm using an current MiKTeX 2.9 ...